# Spring boot Gradle not generating wrapper and not producing runnable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a Spring boot application which would be compiled and run completely in Docker, using a multi-staged dockerfile:

```
###############
#### Build ####
###############
FROM openjdk:13-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY  . .
RUN path/to/gradlew build

################
#### Deploy ####
################
FROM openjdk:13-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/some/path /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [java, some/path/someJar.jar]
```

Two things I can't get straight:

1. There's no gradlew file and gradlew.bat file anywhere in my project. Even though there is a gradle/ directory and in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties I define Gradle version 3.5.1. In settings I tried 'default wrapper' and 'wrapper task configuration'.

[image]

Intellij Idea seems to resolve the gradle executable somehow. Don't know where the executable is.

2. There is some output generated by gradle when building. But nothing that I can run manually or convert to a nice docker command. It basically compiles the java classes and that's it. Running the main class in java doesn't work. Once again, using Intellij Idea 'run' works fine. What does Intellij do?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create wrapper files you need to install Gradle in some other way first. Check [installation documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html). After that you need to run command inside the root folder of your project:

```
gradle wrapper
```

This will generate required `wrapper` and `wrapper.bat` files. Then you can use those scripts to run from your Dockerfile. More details on working with wrapper can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

After you generate the wrapper files you can configure the Intellij by going to `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle` and applying `Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)` radio button. Then IDEA will use it.

Comment: I installed gradle already. Doesn't Intellij Idea use the wrapper already? How can it do that without it being there? And what setting do I need to change in order for Idea to always just use the wrapper?

Comment: If you don't generate wrapper files with `gradle wrapper` command then idea won't use it. Generate the files first.

Comment: sure, I can generate wrappers. But it doesn't make sense to me. How am I even able to go for this option when they're not there? At some point, Idea will download these wrappers and use them. Right?!? Even when I cannot see them anywhere in the project. How can I be sure they will be used?

Comment: IDEA won't download anything. You need to *generate them* yourself using `gradle wrapper` task. IDEA doesn't need to have wrappers to work with gradle projects. As you noticed it determined your local gradle installation. And even with that it only uses it to get information about the project. If you want to use gradle from IDEA you need to explicitly call task from `Gradle toolbar`.

Comment: I've seen Idea download Gradle bins when changing Gradle in the Gradle gradle-wrapper properties file. Where do those bins get stored?